# kops validate cluster fails with "error reading cluster configuration"?

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I'm playing with kops, and set up 2 clusters. After setting up the second cluster, I updated the KOPS_STATE_STORE value in my .profile. Now when I do

```
$ kops get clusters
```

I get

```
cluster not found first-cluster.k8s.local
```

I can't remember what the original KOPS_STATE_STORE was. How can I fix this so first-cluster.k8s.local is gone from kops?

Thanks!

Comment: Login to AWS console and check S3 buckets.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to check it by kops.

Usually, a `KOPS_STATE_STORE` value is an AWS S3 bucket so you can try to check the list of your buckets.